# Pandas: Get unique MultiIndex level values by label

Tags: python, pandas

Say you have this MultiIndex-ed DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['DE','DE','FR','FR'],
                   'biome':['Lake','Forest','Lake','Forest'],
                   'area':[10,20,30,40],
                   'count':[7,5,2,3]})
df = df.set_index(['country','biome'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
                area  count
country biome
DE      Lake      10      7
        Forest    20      5
FR      Lake      30      2
        Forest    40      3
```

I would like to **retrieve the unique values per index level**. This can be accomplished using

```
>>> df.index.levels[0]
['DE', 'FR']

>>> df.index.levels[1]
['Lake', 'Forest']
```

What I would *really* like to do, is to retrieve these lists by **addressing the levels by their name**, i.e. `'country'` and `'biome'`. The shortest two ways I could find looks like this:

```
>>> list(set(df.index.get_level_values('country')))
['DE', 'FR']

>>> df.index.levels[df.index.names.index('country')]
['DE', 'FR']
```

But non of them are very elegant. Is there a shorter and/or more performant way?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Pandas 0.23.0 finally [introduced](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17897) a much cleaner solution to this problem: the `level` argument to `Index.unique()`:

```
In [3]: df.index.unique(level='country')
Out[3]: Index(['DE', 'FR'], dtype='object', name='country')
```

This is now the recommended solution. It is far more efficient because it avoids creating a complete representation of the level values in memory, and re-scanning it.

Answer (score 55):

I guess u want unique values in a certain level (and by level names) of a multiindex. I usually do the following, which is a bit long.

```
In [11]: df.index.get_level_values('country').unique()
Out[11]: array(['DE', 'FR'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is very inefficient, though, as this information of uniqueness is already explicitly stored in the index, so the second of your options, @ojdo, seems to me still to be the best. The use of `unique` is *hundreds* of times slower on my data:
    `timeit df.index.get_level_values(level='co').unique()` gives: 1000 loops, best of 3: **851** µs per loop, while `timeit df.index.levels[df.index.names.index('co')]` gives: 100000 loops, best of 3: **3.08** µs per loop

Comment: @Robert Muil - The problem with that is that index.levels does NOT return updated contents if any rows or columns have been deleted and this is not considered a bug because that's not the approved use of MultiIndexes (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3686). The valid API access for the *current* contents of a MultiIndex is indeed get_level_values. It's tricky for anybody who's used to single Index uniqueness.

Comment: Just a question, really, but why does `indices = df.index.get_level_values('lat').unique()` return the values sorted in reverse? `indices[0] Out[102]: 89.875` vs. `ind2 = df.index.levels[df.index.names.index('lat')]` which give `ind2[0] Out[104]: -89.875`... Sorry for hijacking, just found this behavior curious. Can also confirm unique is *much* slower.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to find the number of levels by calling `df.index.levels[level_index]` where level_index can be inferred from `df.index.names.index(level_name)`. In the above example level_name = 'co'.

The proposed answer by @Happy001 computes the unique which may be computationally intensive.

Comment: This won't work in general (e.g. on sliced dataframes, where some levels are unused)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do the level lookup repeatedly, you could create a map of your index level names to level unique values with:

```
df_level_value_map = {
    name: level 
    for name, level in zip(df.index.names, df.index.levels)
}
df_level_value_map['']
```

But this is not in any way more efficient (or shorter) than your original attempts if you're only going to do this lookup once.

I really wish there was a method on indexes that returned such a dictionary (or series?) with a name like:

```
df.index.get_level_map(levels={...})
```

Where the levels parameter can limit the map to a subset of the existing levels. I could do without the parameter if it could be a property like:

```
df.index.level_map
```

Answer (score -4):

If you already know the index names, is it not straightforward to simply do:
`df['co'].unique()` ?

Comment: You cannot directly access an *index* using the bracket operator. In the above example, `df['co']` gives a KeyError.